# Facebook friend's wall posting through ID

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am trying to post on a Facebook friend's wall, I tried these two methods but none work:

1.

```
//post on wall
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
[variables setObject:@"v" forKey:@"message"];

[graphref doGraphPost:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1389799421/feed"] withPostVars:variables];
//post on wall
```

2.

```
 [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"1389799421/feed"
                      andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test wall post" forKey:@"message"]
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

...and I can't understand why!! On the facebook website I have added the bundle and the permissions.

Comment: I dont think facebook takes kindly to people writing programs to automaticcaly post to walls. You are fighting an uphill battle here... What purpose could you have to do this other then to generate spam ????

Comment: Are you just trying to send a naked post to the facebook server and expecting it to actually post to the wall? If so you are miles aways from getting this to work. How are you validating your connections / sessions before you try to send this post?

Comment: well, I logged in into facebook using the initial HelloFacebook sample. I know it's not the best solution, but the point is that as I have understood it's not possible to send messages, and there isn't any sample code for facebook requests!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to post on a Facebook friend's wall

Facebook recently announced in the developer blog, that posting to another user’s wall through the API [will not be possible any more from Feb 2013 on](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013):

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**
>
> We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

So I think it’s pretty useless starting to develop a feature like that now.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have to open your session with publish permissions. Specifically, you must request the `publish_stream` permission.

```
NSArray * permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
  [self sessionStateChanged:session
                      state:status
                      error:error];
}];
```

If you have publish permissions, you can create and send the request. Make sure you include the `access_token` as one of the parameters. If you don't, you will get authentication errors.

```
NSDictionary * postParameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_textView.text, @"message", FBSession.activeSession.accessToken, @"access_token", nil];
NSString * graphPath = @"ID_NUMBER_HERE/feed";
FBRequest * request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:graphPath parameters:postParameters HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[[request initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:graphPath parameters:postParameters HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Successful posted to Facebook");
  }];
}
```

Comment: Also as noted by CBroe you don't want to be building this API call right now as it will go away soon.